# Preserve sign when squaring values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried this:

```
>>> (-10) ** 2
100
>>> -10 ** 2
-100
```

In short, I was trying to get the output of the negative values squaring as negative.
So I tried the above simple expressions.
Then I tried the same formula on Pandas DataFrame, but I received ll the positive values.

```
>>> listi = [-10,-2,2,3,4,5,-100,-3,4]
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(listi)
>>> df
     0
0  -10
1   -2
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6 -100
7   -3
8    4
>>> df**2
       0
0    100
1      4
2      4
3      9
4     16
5     25
6  10000
7      9
8     16
```

I want to know why this happened? And how I can keep the squaring of the negative values as negative using pandas?

Comment: Hard to imagine that the unary `-` has lower precedence than `**` in `-10 ** 2`. But for this question, I think `df**2` is effectively like `(-10)**2`

Comment: Congrats for your got your 3k man :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiple values by [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) for `-1` for negative values:

```
print (df**2 * np.sign(df))
       0
0   -100
1     -4
2      4
3      9
4     16
5     25
6 -10000
7     -9
8     16
```

Comment: @U9-Forward - yes, another answer explain it.

Comment: Yes, You are correct.  Here are two answers that complete my question as answer. I wish I could have option to accept both as answer :P

Comment: @jezrael That's true, let's hope everyone reads these two answers together

Comment: @JafferWilson Lol :-)

Comment: @JafferWilson Maybe +1 for me as well :-), or did ya :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your original example with `-10` did not preserve the sign of the value, it just made the result of `10**2` negative. That's because [`**` has higher precedence than `-`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

You can preserve the sign using

```
np.sign(df) * df**2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing this because `df` is a variable, and if you try the first code with a variable:

```
>>> a=-10
>>> a**2
100
>>>
```

It would give a positive as well, so it's really about orders of operations, `(` `)` is really a one liner substitute for a two-liner `a = foo` then next line `a**bar`.

One approach (not recommended) would be:

```
>>> df**2 * (df<0).astype(int).replace(0,-1)
       0
0   -100
1     -4
2      4
3      9
4     16
5     25
6 -10000
7     -9
8     16
```

Comment: Your answers is explanation and helps in understanding the issue I came across. Where as the answer I accepted resolved it. As I told have to make tough decisions sometimes... :) Glad you answered my question and have removed the difficulty I had... Thank you for answering my query and keep answering in future... It really helps.. :)

Comment: @JafferWilson Your welcome, thanks so much for your kind reply :-)

Comment: Glad to have people like you who are always ready to help and share there knowledge. I really wish next time in a survey I will add that allow the questioner to accept at least two answers..... Its really tough sometimes. But I have upvoted already ...:)...

Comment: @JafferWilson Thanks for up-voting :-) i am just as glad to have you asking these questions so i can help :-)

Comment: @JafferWilson Btw, i have added my not recommended approach, just to make future readers see that i gave a solution, but it's definitely worthy to accept jezrael's clean and fast approach with `np.sign` :-)

Comment: I always upvote all the helpful question and answers.. It is a great functionality that SO had given. It encourages the questioners and the people answering the queries.. I love SO for that.... :)

Comment: @JafferWilson I do as well, i always up-vote good content, and when i ask, i up-vote most of the answers (few i don't if they don't help me lol), i love SO for that as well :-)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I wish I could even get an option of giving 2 to 3 upvote.. Please SO moderator if you are reading this then I wish I get such option. Even if it is kind of privilege, still worth adding....

Comment: @JafferWilson I up-vote all questions that i answer :-) as well as this one :-)

Comment: @JafferWilson It was great to chat with you, i have to go somewhere now, we can continue this conversation in most likely around 18 or 19 hours... long time, since i am done for today early, we can convert this to chat if you wish :-)

Comment: @JafferWilson 18 hours exactly, can chat again, shall i do a chat for us

Comment: I am really sorry my friend. I was out and was not able to convey you. But it was nice having chat with ya. For the last, I would like to thank you and all others for their precious replies... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192998/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-u9-forward).

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will treat it as `(-10) ** 2`, so you have to detect if it's negative first by yourself.

Use [df.where](https://devdocs.io/pandas~0.19/generated/pandas.dataframe.where#pandas.DataFrame.where) here, if the value is negative, multiple -1 for this data.

```
df * df.where(df>0, -df)
```

Output:

```
    0
0   -100
1   -4
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
6   -10000
7   -9
8   16
```

Answer (score 1):

Another novelty way

```
(df > 0) * df ** 2 - (df < 0) * df ** 2

Out[545]:
       0
0   -100
1     -4
2      4
3      9
4     16
5     25
6 -10000
7     -9
8     16
```